# Вывод данных из checkedListBox с удалением и сохранением в label?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть checkedListBox состоящий из 10 цифр. Выбранные элементы при нажатии кнопки удаляются. Нужно чтобы при выборе в checkedListBox элемента (или элементов) до удаления они записывались в label через запятую. Например если выбирается один элемент, он записывается в label1 и там остается. При выборе следующего элемента или группы элементов в checkedListBox они записываются в label2 и т.д.

При выборе одновременно всех элементов, они записываются в label1 (1,2,3,4...10), а все остальные label остаются пустыми.

Есть код который выводит новый результат, удаляя старый. Не понимаю как его можно подправить чтобы работало

```
label1.Text = " ";
            foreach (var checkedBox in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                label1.Text += checkedBox.ToString() + ",";
            }
```

Comment: `label1.Text = " ";` вот здесь очищаете, можете просто этого не делать.

Comment: Работает но не совсем так как нужно. Если убрать, то запись идет одной строкой. А нужно чтобы каждое нажатие кнопки выводило запись с новой строки. Выбрал 1,2,3, выводится запись - 1,2,3. При следующем выборе, допустим, 4,5, запись шла с новой строки.

Comment: Тогда так `if (label1.Text.Length > 0) label1.Text += Environment.NewLine;`

Comment: Вообще никакие записи не выводит. В foreach  "ненужное присваивание значения checkedBox"

Comment: `+=` заметили? В дизайнере формы увеличьте высоту метки, либо задайте авторазмер. Текст просто не влазит. И то что я выше написал, это вместо `label1.Text = " ";`

Comment: Все работает. Спасибо огромное за помощь!

Comment: А можно как то изменить код чтобы за последним элементом не выводился знак  "," (запятая)? Именно за последним.

Comment: Цикл заменить на `label1.Text += string.Join(",", checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Select(x => x.ToString()));`

Comment: "CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection" не содержит определения "Select"

Comment: `checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast<string>()` вместо Select, или `using System.Linq;` в самом верху добавить.

Comment: Не удается перевести тип объекта int в string

Comment: Ну я ж не телепат, что там на самом деле `.Cast<int>()` значит

Comment: Теперь работает, но при выборе нескольких элементов их вывод дублируется столько же раз в одну строку. Выбрал три элемента, вывод 1,2,3 1,2,3, 1,2,3 ...

Comment: Цикл уберите, я же писал, просто один раз выполнить. Где внимательность?

Comment: Все супер! Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

В общем рабочий код такой:

```
if (label1.Text.Length > 0) label1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
foreach (var checkedBox in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                label1.Text += checkedBox.ToString() + ",";
            }
```

Спасибо за помощь aepot